# Increasing the memory size of an Intellij Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing an Intellij-Plugin. The Plugin needs to have 2GB of HeapMemory (... yes it really needs to ;) ). I found out how I can increase the Memory of the Intellij IDEA VM bis editing the idea64.exe.vmoptions-file like this:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

If i enable the memory indicator, i can see that it worked.

But if i run/debug my plugin out of Intellij, the "sandbox"-Intellij has only 1GB of RAM.

**It throws the flowing warning:**

> High memory usage (free 101 of 914 MB) while dumping threads

How can i increase the RAM of the sandbox-Plugin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting VM Options in run configuration doesn't work for me.

I found more proper way to do it from [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/issues/316). Add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
runIde {
  jvmArgs '-Xmx2G'
}
```

Comment: Changing run configurations did not work for me too. Adding your suggestion to build.gradle worked.

Comment: For kts: `runIde { maxHeapSize = "2g" }`

Comment: complete kts example:
```
tasks {
    val runIde by existing(org.jetbrains.intellij.tasks.RunIdeTask::class) {
        maxHeapSize = "4g"
    }   
}
```